# PHPMailer 5.2 OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer

I'm getting this error with PHPMailer on a PHP 5.6 server.

**Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in class.smtp.php on line 344**

The interesting thing is I'm trying to send email through the local SMTP server @ localhost, and I'm not using SSL or TLS - it's plain SMTP on port 25.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure=''
$mail->SMTPPort //not set
```

The server has a valid SSL Certificate installed for the website domain.

I've read the documentation on GitHub about PHP 5.6 certificate verification failure and it doesn't seem to address this scenario.

I've added this code, but still receive the error:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

I guess the main question is, what SSL certificate, or lack thereof is it complaining about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer's github page [mentions](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/368) this type of error:

> This is covered in the troubleshooting docs. PHP 5.6 verifies SSL certificates by default, and if your cert doesn't match, it will fail with this error. The correct solution is to fix your SSL config - it's not PHP's fault!

I see that you've gone through the trouble of making the PHPMailer settings insecure as is *not recommended* in the [troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Did you notice that requires PHPMailer 5.2.10?

> The correct fix for this is to replace the invalid, misconfigured or self-signed certificate with a good one. Failing that, you can allow insecure connections via the SMTPOptions property introduced in PHPMailer 5.2.10 (it's possible to do this by subclassing the SMTP class in earlier versions), though this is not recommended

There's also suggestions for [enabling debug output](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#enabling-debug-output):

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
```

If you look at the debug output, you may glean more helpful info.

EDIT: this also is not about *your* website's cert, it's about the cert (if any) being hosted by your SMTP mail server endpoint.

Comment: Question 1.  If I'm not setting TLS or SSL why is it checking a certificate at all?  
Question 2. THe only purpose for this SMTP server is for the local PHP application to send notifications.  The SMTP server cannot be connected to from the outside.  In this case, what is the benefit of using SSL or TLS?

I missed the .10 part, but I would think that since I'm not using SSL or TLS that this is moot?

Comment: A1) I'm not sure at all. Turn on the debug and you'll get an idea of the conversation taking place. Your SMTP server may be insisting on SSL? A2) This question is not clear. Your PHP app is running on a web server. the SMTP host settings for PHPMailer can specify a local OR a remote machine which may or many not be accessible from the web server. Again, watching debug output may give you an idea of what happens when the connection attempt happens.

Comment: And it should be apparent that you don't want the debug settings on in your production environment.

Comment: PHPMailer enables encryption automatically if the server offers it. Look up autotls in the docs for how to disable it. What cert it is presenting will also be revealed if you do the openssl tests mentioned in the guide.

Comment: In my original post I did specify that we were using the localhost SMTP server.

Comment: The upshot is I couldn't track this down, and having an active SMTP server on the webserver is an unnecessary risk anyway, so I turned it off and had the client get a SendGrid account, which uses TLS.  Problem solved.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you had an SMTP mail server running on localhost, one would imagine that you were aware of how it was set up, but I know how difficult mail servers can be. My guess (take with lots of salt) is that it was somehow trying to force encrypted connections (even on port 25) and that it was coughing up a self-signed cert or something. SendGrid is the bomb. Glad it's working now. Note that to get your mail delivered effectively, your domain may need some DNS SPF records, domain keys, and possibly other stuff. A good mail reputation is hard to come by.