# PHPMailer not working on CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, phpmailer

Good evening. I've been having some trouble setting PHPMailer on my CI project. The thing is, after a lot of reading, I thought everything was settled, but no.

I'm calling the folder, outside any class, as soon as I open the php tag on my controller:

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Then, inside my public function, I'm doing the following:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 5;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
    $mail->Username = "username";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    // Content //

    $mail->setFrom('somemail@gmail.com');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('somemail@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('someanothermail@gmail.com', 'Contacto');
    $mail->Subject = 'This is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the message';

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Awesome sauce!";
    }
```

So, here's what the debugger says:

```
2017-11-28 14:24:37 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2017-11-28 14:24:38 Connection: opened
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP d15sm21670245qkc.26 - gsmtp"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP d15sm21670245qkc.26 - gsmtp
2017-11-28 14:24:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [190.104.220.99]"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 35882577"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2017-11-28 14:24:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [190.104.220.99]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2017-11-28 14:24:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-11-28 14:24:39 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS"
2017-11-28 14:24:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2017-11-28 14:24:39 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 403]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-11-28 14:24:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-11-28 14:24:39 
2017-11-28 14:24:39 
2017-11-28 14:24:39 
2017-11-28 14:24:39 Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes - read the troubleshooting guide that the error links you to. You have a TLS failure, and it's well documented there, and in many identical questions on here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer 5.2 OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511825/phpmailer-5-2-openssl-error-messages-error14090086ssl-routinesssl3-get-serve)

Comment: Been reading it for quite a while now. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: The important part is "certificate verify failed" - given that it's very unlikely gmail is publishing a bad cert, and you do have ext_ssl installed, it's most likely that your local CA cert database is out of date, as mentioned [in the guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#php-56-certificate-verification-failure), including how to test for it using openssl.

Comment: Maybe related https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en